# Changing Spyne constants

Tags: python, soap, spyne

`spyne.const` has the following

```
REQUEST_SUFFIX = ''
"""The suffix for function response objects."""

RESPONSE_SUFFIX = 'Response'
"""The suffix for function response objects."""
```

How could I configure my own suffixes? I want all my methods' request names to be `<method>RQ` and responses to be `<method>RS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, this should work right before instantiating your `Application` but just to be on the safe side, before the very first import from the spyne namespace, you should do this:

```
import spyne.const
spyne.const.REQUEST_SUFFIX ='RQ'
spyne.const.RESPONSE_SUFFIX ='RS'
```

Comment: It looks library monkey patching. Maybe we should be able to override settings (aka const) for `Service` or `Application` passing it as class metadata or any other way?

Comment: Yes but as of 2.10, that's the answer to your question.

Comment: It actually makes sense to pass them to the Application instance. I'd say introducing a ``spyne.config.Configuration`` object should be the best thing to do.